# Can Bernoulli's Principle be applied to subatomic particles or virtual particles or "the quantum foam"?

Tags: particle-physics, bernoulli-equation, virtual-particles

If we create a pair of rotary wings like those on a helicopter, and spin them in a vacuum, would it be possible for a virtual particle and anti particle pair to spawn, be split by an approaching wing, and take opposing paths around the wing, before re-combining and annihilating?

Would this create a pressure differential as it does on macro scales in fluid dynamics? Does the particle and anti particle pair even need to be split or is it sufficient for multiple such pairs to spawn and move around the wing before annihilation?

If we rotate the wings at relativistic speeds, does this increase the rate at which this occurs and the pressure difference generated?

Comment: I don’t think this is mainstream physics.

Comment: @Ghoster is your concern with the inclusion of quantum foam? Or is it just references to elements of quantum field theory in general such as virtual particles?

Bernoulli's principle is certainly mainstream physics. And I see a number of posts regarding quantum field theory and virtual particles. I can remove "quantum foam" from the title and leave it at virtual particles if that helps clarify.

Comment: My concern is with the notion of using mechanical rotors to do pair-creation from the quantum vacuum. I have no problem with virtual particles or “quantum foam”.

Comment: Ah, I don't mean to imply that the rotors are responsible for pair creation. 

My question is, if a pair were to exist in front of the wing, and continue to exist long enough to be affected by the wing, would Bernoulli's principle apply? Would we see an exchange of kinetic energy for pressure?

Comment: I have never seen this discussed in mainstream physics. I think you are taking classical ideas and trying to apply them to the quantum vacuum.

Comment: *take opposing paths around the wing* Do you understand that quantum particles don’t even *have* trajectories?

Comment: "don’t even have trajectories? "

Right, the wing is moving through them. Think of a pair of virtual particles spawning, and then a wing moving through them, causing them to be moved, displaced around the wing along different paths. The wing is bringing the kinetic energy, not the particles.

As far as your point on this not being discussed. I'd say that is really why I asked the question. I was not able to find much on this. I trusted this would be a welcoming place to ask the question :)

Comment: *I trusted this would be a welcoming place to ask the question.* Your question is still open. However, if members or moderators agree that this isn’t mainstream physics, it will be closed. This site does not deal with non-mainstream physics, as you can read in the help regarding what is [on-topic](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here.